# bitcoin-cli importprivkey to the same user or different users

Tags: bitcoin-cli

If i call the bitcoin-cli importprivkey multiple times, does it import the private key to the same user or to different users? In the bitcoin-cli importprivkey, it does not specify to which user account is the key importing to.

Answer (score 1):

You can set account like that

```
bitcoin-cli importprivkey "myPrivKey" "Account" true
```

if you want to import multi private keys do it like that

```
bitcoin-cli importprivkey "myPrivKey" "Account" false
bitcoin-cli importprivkey "myPrivKey" "Account" false
bitcoin-cli importprivkey "myPrivKey" "Account" false
bitcoin-cli importprivkey "myPrivKey" "Account" true
```

So you don't rescan the entire local block database each time, but the last time.

to import it to default account leave it empty

```
bitcoin-cli importprivkey "myPrivKey" "" true
```

Also please consider stopping using accounts since it will be removed in 0.16 version.

Comment: The 0.16 version will stop using accounts, so how does it manage different users' private keys?

Comment: it's a different question. Please consider ask a new question.